# call a dim from another form

Tags: vb.net, cefsharp

Hello iam trying to call browser from my main form but it is not visible when i type `FrmWebBrowser.browser`.

this is the code from `FrmWebBrowser`.

```
Imports CefSharp
Imports CefSharp.WinForms
Public Class FrmWebBrowser
    Public Sub FrmWebBrowser_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim settings As New CefSettings()
        Dim browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("http://google.com/") With {
            .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        }
        Me.Controls.Add(browser)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to go back basics and learn the fundamentals of the language. Of course you can't access a local variable anywhere but in the method it's declared in. Learn about scope.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#when-can-i-start-executing-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare `browser` at the beginning of your form.

```
dim browser as ChromiumWebBrowser
Public Sub FrmWebBrowser_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim settings As New CefSettings()
    browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("http://google.com/") With {
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    }
    Me.Controls.Add(browser)
End Sub
```